# bad value for restricted picklist field: xxxx","statusCode":"INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST"}],"id":null,"success":false}]}]}

Tags: wordpress

What the problem? Where I should to search error?

```
{"success":false,"data":[{"code":"salesforce_update_data_error","message":[{"errors":[{"fields":["XXXX__c"],"message":"Career Break Reason: bad value for restricted picklist field: xxxx","statusCode":"INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST"}],"id":null,"success":false}]}]}
```

Comment: Please stick to only relevant tags. This question does not appear to have anything to do with the `Salesforce1` app.

Answer (score 1):

On the field XXXX__c in salesforce schema check, there is a flag saying restricted picklist. Disable it.

Comment: That could have serious ramifications... probably better to specify a valid value unless you've done a careful audit.

Comment: I unchecked the Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set

Answer (score 0):

Check the available picklist values under the Record Type in the object definition. Probably you are trying to set a value which is not available for the record type of the record you are creating.

Or uncheck the **Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set** in field definition.

Comment: I unchecked the Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set